# Camera2 не работает при реализации ImageReader

Tags: android, android-camera

Как правильно передавать данные из camera2 в режиме реального времени? Подскажите, будьте добры. уже и так и сяк мучаю `ImageReader`, а ничего не получается. 
пробую добавить `mImageReader` в

```
   mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(...
```

тогда слетает камера ( если помимо surface я подставляю в `createCaptureSession` `mImageReader.getSurface()`
Использую в качестве примера camera2basic, но ничего не получается. делаю все по нему.

Если оставить `mImageReader.getSurface()` незакомментированым то прекращается отображаться изображение с камеры. Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 3):

Оказалось, surfaces, полученные с mImageReader и Textureview имели различные значения width и heigth. поэтому камера не хотела работать корректно